# Given $G: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, is writing $G((x,y))$ more correct than $G(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am reading about multivariable vector-valued functions in a [pdf I found while googling for this topic](http://faculty.bard.edu/bloch/multivariablevectorvalued_notes_gray.pdf).

There is a passage about a function $G: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$:

> We note that if we wanted to write multivariable vector-valued functions absolutely properly, we would write $G((x,y))$ rather than $G(x,y)$, where the inner parentheses in the notation $G((x,y))$ refer to the point (x,y) and the outer parentheses in $G((x,y))$ are the standard parentheses used in the notation of functions.

I understand that there is a point of view by which $G$ is seen as associating a three dimensional vector to each two dimensional point $(x,y)$. Still, why would the notation with the extra parentheses be more correct? Is there a set in stone reason or is this really just a question of taste and preference?

Comment: Isn't that more or less answered in the passage you quoted? If you copy-and-paste $P=(x,y)$ into $G(P)$ you get $G((x,y))$. So if you want to use the simpler expression $G(x,y)$ as a synonym for $G(P)$, you need to make an extra definition to explain what happened to the parentheses that disappeared.

Comment: It just seems to me that to add that passage  would necessitate the point being made actually being important. I can't see how it is that important.

Comment: Whether you think it is "important" or not, you need to make that point once in your mathematical life.  Similarly you also have $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself --- it can mean ordered pairs $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, or as functions $2\to\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., the elements are not $(x,y)$ but $\{(0,x),(1,y)\}$ in the usual relation definition), and many other notations.